# this javascript shows Designed By Shamweel But All Text start Containing Link how to fix that only Shamweel contain link

Tags: javascript

The first code shows `Designed By Shamweel` But all the text is a link

Please help me make the first code to show text "designed by" and then show a text that contain a link "Shamweel"

The output must be designed by (only text) Shamweel (this contains link `https://www.moviesmobster.ga`

I have got this javascript for my template to protect it.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
        if ($('#b').length == 1)
        // check if <a> exists in id="footer-post" and changes <a> address and class
        {
            $('#b a').prop('href', 'http://moviesmobster.ga/').prop('class', 'footer-3').text('Designed By Shamweel');
        }

        if ($('#b').length >= 1 && $('a.footer-3').length == 0) {
            // if link is erased it creates a new one in the same div
            $('<a>', {
                class: 'footer-3',
                text: ' Designed By Shamweel',
                href: 'https://www.moviesmobster.ga/',
            }).appendTo('#b');
        }

        if ($('#b').length == 0 && $('a.footer-3').length == 0) {
            // if div and link are erased it shows an alert and load yahoo
            alert('Template Not Purchased Or Footer Credit Is Removed')
            window.location.href = "https://apksnation.blogspot.com/p/template-not-purchased.html?m=1";
        }
    });
```

```html
<script type = "text/javascript" src = "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>


<div id='b' />
```

Comment: No we do not understand. Please write a proper question and remove all unnecessary text

Comment: I fixed your snippet. Why are you using such a very old jQuery? Also it needs to be https for Chrome to load it

Answer (score 0):

You mean

```js
$(function() {
  const $b = $('#b');
  if ($b.length == 1 && $('a', $b).length == 1)
  // check if <a> exists in id="footer-post" and changes <a> address and class
  {
    $('a', $b)
    .prop('href', 'http://moviesmobster.ga/')
    .prop('class', 'footer-3').text('Shamweel');
  }

  if ($b.length >= 1 && $('a.footer-3').length == 0) {
    // if link is erased it creates a new one in the same div
    $b
      .append("Designed By ")
      .append(
        $('<a>', {
          class: 'footer-3',
          text: 'Shamweel',
          href: 'https://www.moviesmobster.ga/',
        }))
  }

  if ($.length == 0 && $('a.footer-3').length == 0) {
    // if div and link are erased it shows an alert and load yahoo
    alert('Template Not Purchased Or Footer Credit Is Removed')
    window.location.href = "https://apksnation.blogspot.com/p/template-not-purchased.html?m=1";
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id='b' />
```